# How can I build a string in a loop for a dynamic gradient?

Tags: css, loops, less

I want to be able to send in a few different colors and percentages, as a dynamic length list, to a LESS loop, to create a gradient. At the same time, I'd also like to prepend browser prefixes. The reason for this request is because I'm using CSS gradients in place of graphics for speed and minimizing requests.

Here's how I'm doing it now, but I'd like a more flexible solution:

```
.mkgrad(@gclrs, @gdir) {
    @m:length(@list);
    .looppref(@m, @j: 1) when (@j =< @m) {
        @mypref: extract(@list, @j);
        background:~"@{mypref}-linear-gradient(@{gdir}, @{gclrs})";
        .looppref(@m, (@j + 1));
    }
    .looppref(@m);
    .mkdir() when (@gdir = left) {
        background:linear-gradient(to right, @gclrs);
    }
    .mkdir() when (@gdir = top) {
        background:linear-gradient(to bottom, @gclrs);
    }
    .mkdir;
}
```

I'm calling this with the following:

```
@str1:fade(@cgray, 50%);
@str2:fade(@cwhite, 50%);
@str3:fade(@cblack, 50%);
@glist:@str1 0%, @str2 30%, @str3 100%;
background:@str3;
.mkgrad(@glist, left);
```

It's working, but I'd like to be able to merge the @str variables into the above loop so I can just send in a list of colors and percentages, and have it loop the list to build out a string for the background.

Can this be done? Is it possible using a mixin perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the goal correctly what you need is ["Property Values Merge" feature](http://lesscss.org/features/#merge-feature) so together with certain ["Pattern-matching"](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-pattern-matching) optimizations the mixin could look like (assuming Less 1.7.x or higher, but I tested this only with v2):

```
// usage:

@gray:  #010101;
@white: #020202;
@black: #030303;

@gradients: @gray 0%, @white 30%, @black 100%;

div {
    .make-gradient(@gradients, left);
    // or just:
    // .make-gradient(@gray 0%, @white 30%, @black 100%; left);
}

// impl.:

.make-gradient(@gradients, @direction, @fade: 50%) {
    background+: ~"linear-gradient(" @dir;
    .loop(length(@gradients));
    .loop(@i) when (@i > 0) {
        .loop((@i - 1));
        @gradient: extract(@gradients, @i);
        @color:    extract(@gradient, 1);
        @stop:     extract(@gradient, 2);
        background+: fade(@color, @fade) @stop;
    }
    background+_:);

    .dir(@direction);
    .dir(@dir_) {@dir: @dir_}
    .dir(left)  {@dir: to right}
    .dir(top)   {@dir: to bottom}
}
```

I did not include any vendor prefixing because of tools like Autoprefixer (especially since it's now included as a plugin for Less v2), but I guess you'll easily add that yourself if you still find such kludge worthy.

P.S. As suggested in comments below: `background+_:);` works only in v2 (so it's more like an unintended bogus), more safe syntax is obviously `background+_: ~")";`

Comment: Clever idea mate. But that `background+_:);` gives a compiler error when not wrapped within `~""` like `background+_:~")";`. I was testing using lesstester.com (v.1.7.0).

Comment: well done. Probably not easy to understand when you start coding Less. You can also use `background+_: ~")";` in stead of `background+_:);`. That you can not use `+_:(`, `+_:{` and `+_:}`, but can use `+_:)` is probably right and valid, but does not feel consistent,

Comment: That's actually not much different from what I posted. I pride myself in using as few lines as possible when coding, removing needless redundancy while maintaining flexibility. I did use some of what you wrote, but the loop itself isn't needed in your code since the `@gradients` string is already complete for the background. I'm just using my loop for the prefixes. I'm using v.1.7.3 of LESS, installed using npm. A little fuzzy on how to upgrade it.

Comment: "That's actually not much different from what I posted." - I'd said it's vastly different or maybe I just got "I'd like to be able to merge the @str variables into the above loop" totally wrong.

Comment: "I pride myself in using as few lines as possible" - btw. in this context you really should learn how to *not* use `~""` - overusing of that hacks in your original snippet (there `~""` is not necessary everywhere except `@{mypref}-linear-gradient`) makes me bleed.

Comment: I gave the answer to you because you did point out to me that I was asking for something that I was basically already doing, I just didn't try it because I thought it was wrong. In the end, I simply sent the `@gradients` in as `fade(@cgray, 50%) 0%, fade(@cwhite, 50%) 30%, fade(@cblack, 50%) 100%` since I'd have to supply the transparency anyway and this ultimately removes the need for a loop of just colors and positions where a fade might need supplied. There may be times in the future when I need a different fade per color and position.

Comment: @seven-phases-max, Fixed the original code per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use this mixin I created a few weeks back,

[Rotatable Multi-stop SVG linear gradient mixin](http://codepen.io/argh/pen/BLguy)
It is as simple as

```
.multigradient(rgb; 168; @rgb; 2, 1);  // id; degrees; colorstring; ratio
```

once you've built your colorstring, e.g.

```
@rgb: red 0, green 50%, blue 100%;
```

If you look at the code in this mixin, there is a function which builds an svg 'colorstop' string by looping through multiple values.