# How to use less css variable values in variable name?

Tags: css, less

I have tried to use the variable values in variable names, but it wont working. Please let me know is there any way to implement this?

```
@a:1;
@b:2;

@output_@{a}: 3;
@output_@{b}: 4;
```

it should have the variable names like `@output_1` and `@output_2`. Is there any workaround solution to achieve this requirement?

I got this error.

> ParseError: directive options not recognised on line 4, column 8:

Comment: No. As far as I am aware you cannot form variable names using concatenation in Less. However, you can store them as a 2D array (like `@output: 3, 4` and use `extract` function to fetch the corresponding data.

Comment: thanks harry. is it not possible or it can be a feature request. its must need when using loop functionalities in less. it will be create dynamic variables as per loop count.

Comment: I can't comment on feature requests because I am not part of Less core team. Try creating a business case for such a feature and raise in the Less GitHub page. If the team considers it to be a worthy enough value-add then they would get it done.

Comment: What is your objective?

Comment: I would like to create a list of values, it needs some dynamic variables from looping process. like this [list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665124/how-to-create-list-output-in-less)

Comment: You should find another way to do this, otherwise you will end up frying your brain. IMHO, placing a Turing machine in the middle of CSS is a horrible, painful, and wholly unnecessary idea.

Comment: So it couldn't be use like this, ok fine. I ll try other ways. Please share me if you guys have any idea for this. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823833/dynamic-variable-names-in-less-css

Comment: Sorry this isn't relevant to mine. They already define variables and dynamically declared it. In my case it has to be creating the variables dynamically and use it through looping.

Comment: Well, you *don't* need dynamic variables for creating a list of values. I suppose you stepped into this by trying to resolve your Q at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658697. And yes, this an XY Problem and you're trying to solve it wrong way (see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890035).